# Will apple accept a javascript app that usees Google Maps API?

Tags: app-store-connect

Will there be any problems if I send a javascript and html app to the App Store, which uses the Google Maps API. The app is a route planner.

Comment: What makes you think there might be problem?

Answer (score 1):

No, there shouldn't be any problems. My app was essentially just a web frame, which loaded a HTML page which used Javascript and Google Maps API. Apple accepted this fine. My current app uses Google Maps API and displays this on an Apple Map, and again, this was accepted.